# Java WebService (Rest/SOAP) Design Pattern

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc, springsource

We have an application built using Springs/Hibernate/Springs-MVC/.

Now we want to provide RESTful services, planning to use Springs MVC. My question is, is it better to expose the service API directly as Rest Service or write a new Pojo Layer on top of the Service Layer and expose that ?

Will appreciate your insights. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you would want to have a top layer so you can only expose what you want to expose from your Web Service to the outside.